# How to find who last changed am file with perforce?

Tags: jira, perforce, game-development, swarm

I have an idea but I'm not sure how it can be implemented. I use Jira/Perforce/Swarm, and I want to automatically include the name of the engineer who last changed a file. The name of the engineer should be included to the generated bugs/crashes in Jira.

Here is an example: Tod changed file ***TestFile.cpp***. Tod's work has been merged into master branch. Assertion occurred and a bug in Jira was created with reference to the file.

How can we let the system know that Tod was the engineer who changed this file last?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which "the system"?  This information is readily available via `p4 changes` and/or `p4 filelog` -- what limitations do you have on how it can be consumed?

Comment: Apologies, let me give you more context. I am looking to include the last person that changed a file in my Jira bugs. an example would be if my application spit out an assert and a automated jira was created then Id like to have the name of the person who touched that file attached to it. 

I'm looking fog guidance as I don't know where in p4 I should look, and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from the `p4 changes` and/or `p4 filelog` commands:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 filelog TestFile.cpp
//stream/child_stream/TestFile.cpp
... #2 change 290 edit on 2022/03/29 by Tod@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'Tod's awesome change'
... #1 change 289 add on 2022/03/29 by Samwise@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 (text) 'added file'

C:\Perforce\test>p4 changes -m1 TestFile.cpp
Change 290 on 2022/03/29 by Tod@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 'Tod's awesome change'
```

If your automation is able to identify specific lines of code that introduced bugs, you might also find `p4 annotate` useful for tracing those lines of code to specific Perforce revisions/users:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 annotate -Tu TestFile.cpp
//stream/child_stream/TestFile.cpp#2 - edit change 290 (text)
     1:      Samwise 2022/03/29 asdfasdf
     2:          Tod 2022/03/29 "tod"
```

Comment: Sweet. Let me give it a try